# Scroll view when collection view scrolls

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, autolayout

I want to scroll the `UIView` when collection view scrolls as shown in below video

[image]

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print(scrollView.contentOffset.x)

    let contentSize = self.propertyImageCollectionView.contentSize

    let xOffSet = (((scrollView.contentOffset.x * self.propertyImageCollectionView.frame.width) / (contentSize.width - self.progressViewWidthConstratint.constant)))

    let xValue = xOffSet + ((self.progressViewWidthConstratint.constant * self.progressViewLeadingConstraint.constant) / self.propertyImageCollectionView.frame.width)

    print( self.progressViewWidthConstratint.constant)
    print( xOffSet)
    print(xValue)

     if xValue > 0 && xValue < self.propertyImageCollectionView.frame.width - self.progressViewWidthConstratint.constant{
        self.progressViewLeadingConstraint.constant = xValue
    }
}
```

The view is not scrolling upto end of screen. It stops scrolling before some points. Where am I lacking in my code. I also tried to use `KVO` but not succeed. Do you have any alternative approach?

Comment: What is the contentInset on the `propertyImageCollectionView`?

Comment: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)